# Best Practice for a database that continues to expand with more tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am a Ruby on Rails application developer and have helped with the creation of a database "college_a", containing information about the college I work for.

Initially, "college_a" contained tables for apps, apps_auths, and apps_roles. Over the past years it has expanded to contain tables for employees, job info, and supervisors ... all in the "college_a" database. I am looking at saving data about email accounts and am wondering if there are any drawbacks to continuing to add more tables to "college_a" or should I start looking at creating a new database representing data on email accounts which will need to reference data from the "college_a.people" table.

Not having experience with the maintenance/usage of an ever expanding database or needing to query multiple databases to gather needed data, is why I am asking if there are any negatives from continuing to add more tables to "college_a" database?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if you've just given a summary but at the moment your database structure as outlined doesn't seem to have a massive number of tables.

Comment: There are 20 tables right now. I am looking at best practice as we continue to add more and more tables each year. So no major drawbacks in continuing to add more tables?

Comment: Not a massive db expert but I'd say no [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html)

Comment: Thank you @j-dexx ... I am definitely under the 4 billion table mark.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no problem in keep adding tables, as long as they are well designed and justified. In other words, I don't think there is such thing as too much tables, but you must make an effort to keep it well designed.

This means there shouldn't be any redundancy, you should try to keep the database normalized, you should try to keep a documentation about it, etc.

I found this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/) that enumerates some database mistakes that I think you may find helpful.